# Why Newton's method converges to second root in parabola?

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions, newton-raphson, fixed-point-iteration

Have been looking for the solution for 2 hours, decided to try here instead.
We have this unprecise picture, let me try to explain it.
[Picture of parabola with 2 roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NedJl.png)

How starting guess $x_0$ defines towards what root the converging will be taking place? So my professor said that in the case described on the picture although $x_0$ is far away from $x_2$, it will still converge to that point, instead of  $x_1$ point, that seems more logical as $x_0$ is near $x_1$.

Why that happens? It has to do with double roots, or the $x_0$ is still too far away from $x_1$ and that's why imprecision comes in?

Comment: The statement of the question is false. If you start in the $x_0$ of the picture the Newton method converge to $x_1$. If you want to study the Newton's method in more extension I will recommend the book *Analysis I* of Amann and Escher, one of the final chapters is about that, and there are a lot of exercises that include some theorems to prove about the convergence of the Newton's method and how it works in each case.

Comment: I'm not sure about this example (in fact, I think your statement isn't correct, judging by my experience with Newton's method for square roots), but you can think about a more extreme example. Suppose you're at a point $x_0$ which is actually really close to a root (maybe 0.1 away, with $f(x_0)=1$ say) but the derivative at that particular point is really tiny (maybe 0.001). Then Newton's method will send you far away from where you started. This can happen if the derivative changes rapidly in between $x_0$ and the root. It does not require the root to be a double root.

Comment: @Masacroso, this might be my error, because I redrew the picture during the class. Although it was something similar. The general idea was, that even if $x_0$ is near $x_1$ not $x_2$, in special case it might still guide us to $x_2$ and converge there. I am guessing, when that happens.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't think my professor was wrong, it's just my drawing problem, I guess.

Comment: @Moontego the general idea is true, but the example you shows is not the case. The reason is that in the picture starting in $x_0$ the Newton's method defined a monotonic sequence that converge to $x_1$, this can be proved by the characteristics for this case: $f$ is convex and positive. But you can see it geometrically drawing some lines.

Comment: We are unanimously agreed that your professor was wrong. Are you sure that's what they said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Newton's method what it does geometrically is define over the $x$-axis a sequence of points $(x_n)$ through the iterative construction of tangents to the function.

Let define the perfect interval $[\min\{x_0,r\},\max\{x_0,r\}]$ for some root $r$, that is, $f(r)=0$, and some starting point for the iteration $x_0$.

If $f$ is convex (alternatively concave) in this interval and $f(x_0)>0$ (alternatively $f(x_0)<0$) then the sequence starting by $x_0$ converges monotonically to $r$.

**Proof:** without lose of generality suppose that $f$ is convex and the interval is $[x_0,r]$ (as in your example). By the definition of convexity every tangent line to $f$ is below $f$, that is, $h(x)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in[x_0,r]$ and $h$ being any tangent line to some point in $(x_0,r)$ (I exclude the endpoints for some trivial cases where $h$ could be zero).

The tangent to $(x_0,f(x_0))$ (for differentiable $f$) is

$$h(x)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)\tag{1}$$

Equating $h(x)=0$ above we can define the standard Newton's iterative sequence

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\tag{2}$$

Because $f$ is convex then $h(x)\le f(x)$, then if $f(x_0)>0$ we have, from (1) and (2), that $h(x_1)=0\le f(x_1)$, and by induction $f(x_n)\ge0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

WLOG suppose that $f'(x_n)>0$ and $f'(x_{n+1})<0$, then $f$ have a local minimum $m\in(\min\{x_n, x_{n+1}\},\max\{x_n, x_{n+1}\})$ such that $f(m)>0$ (because a convex function is above of it tangent lines and as I showed before $f(x_n)\ge 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$) what is a contradiction with the assumption that $f$ has a zero in $r$, so $f'(x_n)$ have the same sign for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

From the same sign of $f'$ in $(x_n)$, and because a convex function is above to it tangent lines, and because (2), is easy to check that the sequence $(f(x_n))\downarrow 0$ what implies that $(x_n)\to r$ monotonically.

For $f$ concave we can prove a similar result when $f(x_0)<0$.

---

All this ugly proof (if it is written correctly, what Im not completely sure) can be "sorted", for the exemplification of the phenomenon for this specific case for $f$ convex and $f(x_0)>0$, with a graph were we show how the sequence works for the case where $f$ is convex and $f(x_0)>0$ but by now Im unable to graph it in some graphic software.

In short words: $x_n$, for all $n\in\Bbb N$, is at the left of the root $r$ of the example, then it cannot be possible that $(x_n)$ converge to some root at the right of $r$.

---

Using some geogebra applet like [this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/DGFGBJyU) we can see some graphical examples about how the Newton's method build the recursion that approach to some root.

This is an example for the case discussed above when $f$ is convex and $f(x_0)>0$ (the red lines are tangents, and the blue lines represent the recursion from one tangent line to other):

[image]

And this is an example when the recursion goes to a root far away from the starting point:

[image]

Of course is possible that the Newton's method doesnt converge at all to any root of $f$.

Comment: I'd like to put in that the phenomenon in the OP does exist, even though it does not occur in quadratic cases. The idea behind an example is to have two roots $r_1<r_2$, to have a "convex trap" like Masacroso's answer to the left of $r_1$, and to have a point $x_0$ to the right of $r_2$ so that $x_0-r_1<\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$.

Comment: @Ian of course the phenomenon of the OP occurs, I know. I write this comment to context this answer so it cannot be misinterpreted. In some time I will improve the answer building two graphs: one showing what I said above and other showing what you said about the phenomenon of convergence to some root more far away of other root respect to the starting point.

Comment: (Cont.) Using Hermite interpolation we can construct a cubic polynomial such that $f(-1)=0,f(0)=0,f(1)=2,f'(1)=0.02$; the result turns out to be $x(x+1)-1.49x(x+1)(x-1)=-1.49x^3+x^2+2.49x$. Then Newton's method started at $x_0=1$ sends you into the "convex trap" to the left of $-1$, ultimately converging there instead of at $0$. (I fixed a minor error in the previous version of this comment after the 5 minute cutoff.)

Comment: Guys, I am so thankful for all those answers. I tried to understand everything you wrote and now understand this case much better. I am so thankful, that people like you exist. I wish I had the right to give points, but I have very low reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

In general, even if you know all the roots of a polynomial it is not easy to say to which root Newton's method will converge for a given starting point. This is because for general (complex valued) polynomials the sets of those point become fractals. Below is a picture where each color corresponds to the root of $p(z) = z^3 -1$ the Newton method converges against.

[[image: Newton fractal of <span class=]$z^3-1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yt2Y.jpg)

Comment: Is this specific to $\mathbb{C}$, or is the fractal geometry present in just $\mathbb{R}$ as well? In the picture it looks like the problem is not present in $\mathbb{R}$, but the axes are not labeled so it is hard to tell where $\mathbb{R}$ is.